# running imagemagick convert (console application) from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagemagick, subprocess, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to rasterize some fonts using imagemagick with this command which works fine from a terminal:

```
convert -size 30x40 xc:white -fill white -fill black -font "fonts\Helvetica Regular.ttf" -pointsize 40 -gravity South -draw "text 0,0 'O'" draw_text.gif
```

Running the same command using subprocess to automate it does not work:

```
try:
    cmd= ['convert','-size','30x40','xc:white','-fill','white','-fill','black','-font','fonts\Helvetica Regular.ttf','-pointsize','40','-gravity','South','-draw',"text 0,0 'O'",'draw_text.gif']
    #print(cmd)
    subprocess.check_output(cmd,shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e)
    print(e.output)
```

.

```
Command '['convert', '-size', '30x40', 'xc:white-fill', 'white', '-fill', 'black', '-font', 'fonts\\Helvetica Regular.ttf', '-pointsize', '40', '-gravity', 'South', '-draw', "text 0,0 'O'", 'draw_text.gif']' returned non-zero exit status 4
b'Invalid Parameter - 30x40\r\n'
```

Comment: Why are you running it with `shell = True` ?

Comment: @gahooa For some reason, I have never been able to run anything without `shell=True`. I tried it with `shell=False` but that gives me the same error. Anyway, it is not unsafe because I am not using any  untrusted input.

Comment: For starters, take `str.join(' ', cmd)` and copy+paste that to the command line to see if it still works.

Comment: @gahooa That works if I quote the `fonts\Helve...` and `text 0,0 'O'`. I think this is normal because the quotes are only there because of the space in the argument and the shell strips away the quotes before passing them to the program

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out: It turns out that **windows has its own `convert.exe` program in `PATH`**.

The following code prints `b'C:\\Windows\\System32\\convert.exe\r\n'`:

```
try:
    print(subprocess.check_output(["where",'convert'],stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True))
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e)
    print(e.output)
```

Running the same code in a terminal shows that imagemagick's `convert` shadows Windows' `convert`:

```
C:\Users\Navin>where convert                                                    
C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.3-Q16\convert.exe                              
C:\Windows\System32\convert.exe
```

.

I did not restart python after installing ImageMagick so its `PATH` still pointed to the Windows version.

Using the full path works:

```
try:
    cmd= ['C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.3-Q16\convert','-size','30x40','xc:white','-fill','white','-fill','black','-font','fonts\Helvetica Regular.ttf','-pointsize','40','-gravity','South','-draw',"text 0,0 'P'",'draw_text.gif']
    print(str.join(' ', cmd))
    print('stdout: {}'.format(subprocess.check_output(cmd,shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)))
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e)
    print(e.output)
```

Comment: I don't know why but in OSX(10.11) works only without shell=True.

Comment: @AndréDuarte Yep, I did the same thing 4 years ago when I asked this question. Though since then, I realized that ImageMagick is a piece of crap and I'd much rather use an image library with a real API.