# Convert image using image magick via java command says error

Tags: java, command-line, imagemagick

I need to convert all the tif, jpeg, gif to jpg format. For this am using

```
        ProcessBuilder pb2 = new ProcessBuilder("convert.exe", "\"" +dest.toString()+ "\" ", "\" " + dest.getParent().toString().concat("/").concat(dest.getName().toString().substring(0, dest.getName().toString().lastIndexOf(".")).concat(".jpg"))+ "\" " );
        System.out.println("convert " + "\"" + dest.toString() + "\" " + "\" " + dest.getParent().toString().concat("/").concat(dest.getName().toString().substring(0, dest.getName().toString().lastIndexOf(".")).concat(".jpg")) + "\" " );
        pb2.redirectErrorStream(true);
        try {
            Process p2 = pb2.start();
            System.out.println("jpg done for " + dest.getName());
            new Thread(new InputConsumer(p2.getInputStream())).start();
            try {
                System.out.println("Exited with: " + p2.waitFor());
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ImageFileCopy.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ImageFileCopy.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

It is saying error 
                    "Invalid parameter - and 
                     Exited with: 4"

I also tried giving "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16\convert.exe". If i use full path system not showing error but wating for long time.

Any idea plz suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `ProcessBuilder` there's no need to "quote" your parameters, this is the point of using `ProcessBuilder`, it will guarantee that each separate parameter is passed as an argument to the command

```
ProcessBuilder pb2 = new ProcessBuilder(
    "convert.exe",
    dest.toString(), 
    dest.getParent().toString().concat("/").concat(dest.getName().toString().substring(0, dest.getName().toString().lastIndexOf(".")).concat(".jpg")));
```

I also agree with Rafael's suggestion, a wrapper API will make life a LOT easier ...

[face palm]...Windows has it's own convert program which is accessible via the `PATH` environment variable.

Even when I used `pb.directory` and set the directory to the install location of ImageMagick, it still picked up the Windows/MS program...

Try adding the full path to `convert.exe`

```
ProcessBuilder pb2 = new ProcessBuilder(
    "C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16\\convert.exconvert.exe",
    dest.toString(), 
    dest.getParent().toString().concat("/").concat(dest.getName().toString().substring(0, dest.getName().toString().lastIndexOf(".")).concat(".jpg")));
```

And thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016974/running-imagemagick-convert-console-application-from-python) for pointing it out...

Comment: if i run without "quote" also it is saying same error

Comment: similarly when i used  ProcessBuilder pb2 = new ProcessBuilder(Config.imagemagickrootpath + "/" + "convert", "-density", "100", dest.toString(),"-background", "white", "-alpha", "remove", dest.toString(), dest.getParent().toString().concat("/").concat(dest.getName().toString().substring(0, dest.getName().toString().lastIndexOf(".")).concat(".jpg")) );. System is creating two images-o, images-1. May i know what is the reason?

Comment: Have you tried placing the "source" file reference as the first option (don't have imagemagic in front of me to check)

Comment: Duplication is due to "dest.toString()" called twice in the argument. fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use [im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/) to call ImageMagick from your java code.

It is opensource, has [API to call many ImageMagick functions](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/api/) and is easy to use.

invokation of an ImageMagick resize-function (for example) looks like that:

```
// create command
ConvertCmd cmd = new ConvertCmd();

// create the operation, add images and operators/options
IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
op.addImage("myimage.jpg");
op.resize(800,600);
op.addImage("myimage_small.jpg");

// execute the operation
cmd.run(op);
```

Check this simple [developer's guide](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/docs/dev-guide.html) for more information.

Comment: how to download the im4java jar

Comment: @Dhinakar here you go: http://im4java.sourceforge.net/#download and there's the link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/im4java/files/  just download source code and include it to your project.

Comment: Use ConvertCmd class as it is shown in my answer. Also in my answer there are links to full API and developer's guide, to let you customize this example as you wish.

Comment: In java code we can set the path by following way
String myPath="C:\\Programs\\ImageMagick-6.3.9-Q16"; ProcessStarter.setGlobalSearchPath(myPath);