# Cross-platform way to run external process from java?

Tags: java, windows, exec

I need to call an external program from Java such as ImageMagick's `convert`. It fails to work on Windows unless I put `cmd /c` before the actual command.

```
String source = "test.jpg";
String result = "test-thumbnail.jpg"; 
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder().command("cmd", "/c", "convert", source, "-thumbnail", "295x", result);
Process process = builder.start();
```

How to avoid using `cmd /c` so that my code works on OS other than Windows?

Without `cmd /c` I get into very similar problem as described here: [running imagemagick convert (console application) from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016974/running-imagemagick-convert-console-application-from-python) - that there exists a native Windows `convert.exe` which is being called rather than ImageMagick's `convert.exe`. It seems like `PATH` is not picked by environment of the child process.

I have double checked that my system `PATH` has ImageMagick directory before `C:\Windows\system32`. Also the command itself runs perfectly fine when I type it into the Windows command line.

Comment: Just for debug purposes, try going to C:\Windows\System32 and renaming `convert.exe` as `msconvert.exe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the OS.

```
private static String OS = System.getProperty("os.name")
```

Comment: Yes, well, this will work, but I would like to understand why `cmd /c` is required in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but I think that while un linux commands are the main program of the OS, on windows, cmd is just one more program.

Comment: `cmd` is the process to start (basically it opens a new console window), `/c` tells that don't keep the console alive after the process run (so it coles itself).